# Access Mark a Record if Just One Record Contains a Specific Value

Tags: ms-access

[My Current Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7848m.png)

I would like to add a field that classifies each student by whether or not they failed a course. For example, if they failed a class the new field might have them marked as 'x'. If a student did not fail any course they may be marked as 'y'. How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Open table in design view, add field, open in datasheet view, enter data. Or better, calculate in a query.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate in query using nested query or domain aggregate function:

```
SELECT *, IIf(SELECT Count(*) FROM tablename AS Q1 WHERE Q1.PassOrFail = "Fail" AND Q1.Student_ID=tablename.StudentID)=0, "Y", "X") AS Cat 
FROM tablename;
```

or

```
SELECT *, IIf(DCount("*", "tablename", "PassOrFail = 'Fail' AND Student_ID=" & [Student_ID])=0, "Y", "X") AS Cat 
FROM tablename;
```

Domain aggregate functions can cause slow performance in large dataset.